# Iframe not working correctly in my Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want the embedded website to show on the right of the sidebar menu, but the embedded website is showing within the sidebar menu. When the user presses control chart under Cell Culture, the embedded website should show clearly to the right. Here is an image of my issue [image: dashboard]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAKaC.png)

How can I fix this error?
Here is my code:

```
    library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- 
    dashboardPage(skin="black",
                  dashboardHeader(title = "CPV Dashboard ", titleWidth = 450),
                  dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(
                          menuItem("Tab 1", tabName = "tab 1", icon = icon("medicine"),
                                   menuItem("Cell Culture",
                                            menuItem("Control Chart",                     mainPanel(fluidRow(
                                                htmlOutput("frame")))))))


                      ),
                  
                  dashboardBody())

server = function(input, output, session){
    observe({ 
        
        test <<- paste0("https://google.com") #sample url
    })
    output$frame <- renderUI({
        input$Member
        my_test <- tags$iframe(src=test, height=800, width=800)
        print(my_test)
        my_test
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need the `dashBoardBody` inside the `dashboardPage`.

As far as I can see your current code isn't doing that.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <-
  dashboardPage(
    skin = "black",
    dashboardHeader(title = "CPV Dashboard ", titleWidth = 450),
    dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(
        "Tab 1",
        tabName = "tab 1",
        icon = icon("medicine"),
        menuItem("Cell Culture",
                 menuItem("Control Chart"))
      )
    )),
    
    dashboardBody(mainPanel(fluidRow(htmlOutput("frame"))
  ),

))

server = function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    test <<- paste0("https://google.com") #sample url
  })
  output$frame <- renderUI({
    input$Member
    my_test <- tags$iframe(src = test,
                           height = 800,
                           width = 800)
    print(my_test)
    my_test
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks @norie, this works! Is it possible to have the website load ONLY if the user clicks "control chart"? right now the website automatically pops up, without the user having to click anything

Comment: Hi how come google is not displayed? I get an error of declined connection